# Facebook URL User Profile Scheme

Tags: iphone, facebook, url, ios

The recent updates to the Facebook application have broken some of the custom URL schemes, up until recently calling:

```
fb://profile/12345
```

would open the FB iPhone app to the profile of the user with facebookID 12345

This is however, no longer the case. 
I have been trying to find out if the URL has been replaced by a different one, but no luck. Anyone has any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I can get the profile from the webpage via http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1234567890, not sure how that will translate to the iPhone app.

Last update to the Facebook app was on Friday, so it could have been a change to the app.  Here's the post on the update.  Someone claims that is only compatible with iOS 4.1, another poster claims previous versions have new bugs (so the backend might have changed).
http://www.facebook.com/iphone/posts/176886075659410

Comment: the thing is (i just ran a test) that the Sync contacts functionality of the FB app uses that same URL scheme as I've mentioned above. Those don't work either, so it must be a bug in the app...